# Efficiently Saving 60K Records in database with django rest frame work

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework, celery

I have an endpoint (eg http://localhost:8000/api/create/) which creates new record in mysql db with django rest framework

**views.py**

```
class CreateItem(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  .
  .
  .
  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
```

**serializers.py**

```
class CreateItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now i have a requirement that, 60K individual HTTP request will be made in this endpoint with the help of script in small time frame

How can i handle it most efficiently, which will take less time and resource.

I read about Django atomic and celery task but completely confused how to make use of it for this requirements.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So the simplest way to do this is to wrap your code inside an atomic transaction.

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    serializer.create() # This code goes where you are calling the serializer.create() function, NOT inside the serializer itself else it's useless
```

What this will do is it will buffer all your inserts and then execute them all at once.

bulk_create is even faster but you can't do it with serializers.

Comment: so if i do 

`if serializer.is_valid():
   with transaction.atomic():
      serializer.save()`

this will have my requirement?

Comment: No. The whole point of using transaction.atomic() is to group together multiple inserts. If you do it on a per-object basis it is useless.

You need to do it from a higher point in your code where all the serializers are being processed.

Comment: i only have one modelserializer in serializer.py file for this view . what if i do `@transaction.atomic decorator in def perform_create` is this what you mean by higher point?

Comment: @young_minds1 No

You must have a for loop in your code that goes through all the 60k+ instances you serialize one by one. The with transaction.atomic() is supposed to be before that for loop. So that all the serializations and their save() happens inside a single execution of transaction.atomic()

Comment: but i will get data from every HTTP post request on that endpoint which makes 60K POST request in small time frame since it will be executed by script.  how will i ran for loop on it ? since i am getting data in single HTTP request

Comment: @young_minds1 In that case what you are asking for is impossible. I thought you were doing a batch operation.

If it's thousands of separate requests there is no way to combine them since they are already separate.

You can send them all into a Celery queue instead of writing them to database, then write them to database in batches with transaction.atomic() with a Celery worker

Comment: could you please help me with the snippets of celery and atomic. since i am confused how will i achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create your objects by passing data through an HTTP request, Celery won't do it as you need first to send it to Django.

However, you could increase performance by creating multiple objects on the same request:

You could create an action `bulk_create` and create a `BulkSerializer` with only one field: `objects = MySerializer(many=True)`.

And try something like that:

```
class CreateItem(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  .
  .
  .
  @action(methods=["post"], detail=False)
  def bulk_create(self, request):
    serialized = BulkSerializer(data=request.data)
    serialized.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    for validated_data in serialized.validated_data["objects"]:
      # Create object here
    return Response({"status": "ok"})
```

(You could improve this by reusing the same logic as in `create`, using some `try / except` to handle if one fail, and use `MULTISTATUS` for Response, but here's the gist)

That way, you could create your models, let say, 100 by 100 or 1000 by 1000.